# Why not use "from" to replace "with" in the sentence"He suffers terribly with his feet."?

Tags: prepositions

> He suffers terribly **with** his feet.

Why not use the preposition "from"?

What is the meaning of "with" here?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't ever say this (AmE). I would say "He suffers terribly due to foot pain"... or something similar.

Comment: Although somewhat less common, [*suffers **in** his feet*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suffers+in+his+feet%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and [*suffers **from** his feet*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22suffers+from+his+feet%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) both also occur, and effectively "mean" the same thing.

Comment: Where I come from (US, mid-Atlantic) we do not say "He suffers from his feet", though we would say "He suffers from foot problems" or "He is having foot trouble".

Comment: Have you looked up _with_ in a dictionary? It can be used in many different ways - [have a look](https://www.wordnik.com/words/with). Moreover, one of _with_'s definitions is _In regard to_ – a "catch-all" definition which allows the word to be used in a mulititude of ways. Lastly, in a question like this, you really should tell us where you found the sentence. Otherwise, we have no way of knowing who wrote it. I don't evaluate all sentences the same; I want to know: was this written by an established author, a journalist, or some random blogger? It makes a difference.

Comment: It may also be the case that the suffering he endures due to his feet mat not actually be from pain in his feet.  For example perhaps his feet are fine, causing no pain, for everyday commonplace activities but he is unable to a accompany his wife on mountaineering expeditions and has to suffer her absence at home for months at a time.  ***with*** allows this interpretation while ***from*** doesn’t as easily.